# How to upgrade apacheds from 2.0.0-M19 to 2.0.0-23? Please share documents or steps would be appreciated it

Tags: upgrade, restore

I need to upgrade apacheds from 2.0.0-M19 to 2.0.0-M23. Kindly share steps or documents. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you do anything you should export the existing LDAP database to an LDIF file!

Export:

> ldapsearch -h localhost -p 10389 -D uid=admin,ou=system -w secret -LLL > ldap-export.ldif

Then import on the new server it in a similar fashion:

> ldapmodify -h localhost -p 10389 -D uid=admin,ou=system -w secret -a -f ldap-export.ldif

I've always done the "upgrade" by building a clean box, installing the new version of ApacheDS to it and then re-importing the data. The main thing to be sure of is that you get all (if any) schema changes but do not overwrite any conflicting schemas in the new version.

The "-a" switch means ADD to the existing data (instead of replace it) so if there is a conflict it will tell you. Expect to do this a few times until you get it right :)

Comment: Since the apacheds will be running on a different box. How will the new box will be able to  connect to old box and re-import the data?

Comment: You will need to copy the file to the new server before importing it (and point clients to the new server)

Comment: [root@ip] # ldapsearch -h localhost -p 10390 -D uid=admin,ou=system -w secret -LLL > ldap-export.ldif
-bash: ldapsearch: command not found

Comment: command 'ldapsearch' did not work for me. Kindly advice

Comment: install the ldap utilities. You should be googling this question, not asking it here...